# compare sum of one table with a field on another table

Tags: join

I have two tables `invoice` and `allocation`. The common id is

```
Invoice.invoice_id = Allocation.Invoice_RK
```

The allocation table may have multiple rows with one invoice_id and amount column. The invoice table has one row for one invoice_id with allocated_invoice_amount.

Actually Sum of Allocation.Amount should be equal to Invoice.Allocated_Invoice_Amount.

Please assist me with a query where Invoice.Allocated_Invoice_Amount not equal to sum Allocation.Amount where the Invoice.invoice_id = Allocation.Invoice_RK

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Please provide your tables and data in the form of DDL (`CREATE TABLE foo (...`) and DML (`INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...`). Sites like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/) one can be a convenient way to do this. Please also tell us what server you are using! There are a few articles on my profile on how to ask questions here - you might want to take a look? Good questions get good answers - help us to help you! :-)

Comment: In addition to what Vérace wrote: see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables in your question text

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) you are targeting for this question, but here is a SQL Server solution which you could probably adapt.

```
--demo setup
set nocount on;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Invoice;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Allocation;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Invoice (Invoice_Id int, Allocated_Invoice_Amount decimal(11,2));
CREATE TABLE dbo.Allocation (Allocation_Id int, Invoice_RK int,  Amount decimal(11,2));

INSERT INTO dbo.Invoice(Invoice_Id,Allocated_Invoice_Amount) values(1,100);
INSERT INTO dbo.Invoice(Invoice_Id,Allocated_Invoice_Amount) values(2,200);

--The allocation amounts for this Invoice_RK sum to the Allocated_Invoice_Amount for Invoice 1
INSERT INTO dbo.Allocation(Allocation_Id,Invoice_RK, Amount) values(1,1,50);
INSERT INTO dbo.Allocation(Allocation_Id,Invoice_RK, Amount) values(2,1,50);

--The allocation amounts for this Invoice_RK DO NOT sum to the Allocated_Invoice_Amount for Invoice 2
INSERT INTO dbo.Allocation(Allocation_Id,Invoice_RK, Amount) values(3,2,100);
INSERT INTO dbo.Allocation(Allocation_Id,Invoice_RK, Amount) values(4,2,90);

--solution
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Invoice i
WHERE i.Allocated_Invoice_Amount <> (
        SELECT SumAmount
        FROM (
            SELECT Invoice_RK
                ,sum(Amount) AS SumAmount
            FROM dbo.Allocation
            WHERE Invoice_RK = i.Invoice_Id
            GROUP BY Invoice_RK
            ) a
        )
```

---

```
 Invoice_Id | Allocated_Invoice_Amount |
|------------|--------------------------|
| 2          | 200.00                   |
```